# Simplify $ (a^{-2} - b^{-2})/(a^{-1}-b^{-1})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Simplify $$ (a^{-2} - b^{-2})/(a^{-1}-b^{-1}).$$

My answer is $\frac{1}{a+b}$. Am I correct?

I had a precalculus final today and remembered this is a question.

Comment: One "simplifies" or "reduces" an expression, not "solves" it.

Comment: You can substitute values to see whether a proposed equation is valid. If you try $a = 1$ and $b = 2$, then the original expression works out to $\frac{3}{2}$, while your proposed simplification becomes $\frac{1}{3}$. Therefore, the original expression is not equivalent to your simplification.

Comment: $\frac{1}{a+b} \color{#c00}\neq \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

To make life easier define $x=\frac{1}{a}$,$y=\frac{1}{b}$. So the expression becomes $$\frac{x^2-y^2}{x-y}=\frac{(x+y)(x-y)}{x-y}=x+y=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to simplify this expression then notice that:

$$\frac{(\frac{1}{a})^{2}-(\frac{1}{b})^{2}}{\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$$

by difference of squares.

Comment: "difference of squares" is nice shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

This is same as what others are showing, since you are having trouble, I am simplifying each step below.

$\Large \frac{a^{-2}-b^{-2}}{a^{-1}-b^{-1}}=\frac{\frac{1}{a^2}-\frac{1}{b^2}}{\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{b}}=\frac{\frac{b^2-a^2}{a^2b^2}}{\frac{b-a}{ab}}=\frac{b^2-a^2}{a^2b^2}\times \frac{ab}{b-a}=\frac{(\color{red}{b-a})(b+a)}{(\color{blue}{ab})(ab)}\times \frac{\color{blue}{ab}}{\color{red}{b-a}}=\frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{a^{-2} - b^{-2}}{a^{-1} - b^{-1}} = \frac{(a^{-1})^2 - (b^{-1})^2}{a^{-1} - b^{-1}} = \frac{(a^{-1} - b^{-1})(a^{-1} + b^{-1})}{a^{-1} - b^{-1}} = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}
$$

Comment: This looks unnecessarily complicated

Comment: At first glance looks complicated, but it is an equivalent of the above solution.